# Add header link via magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I want to **Add header links via magento admin**.I know it can be added/removed via XML files. In my case, admin must decide Links to be viewed in header links. Is there any extensions to to this?.

For Example: Sometime admin wants to add **"Offer of the day"** link in header links, sometime admin wants to remove this link. Also there should be option to add/remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it through XML and just make a config setting that enables/disables it.

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="[module]" ifconfig="[module]/offer/enabled">
            <label>Offer of the day</label>
            <url>URL HERE</url>
            <title>Offer of the day</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
         </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then create in your module inside `system.xml` this setting:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <[module] translate="label" module="[module]">
            <label>[Module]</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <offer translate="label">
                    <label>Offer of the day</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>
                </offer>
            </groups>
        </[module]>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Replace `[module]` with your module name

Comment: Hai Marius thanks for your answer. As already said, my admin must decide adding/deleting/enabling/disabling header links. I know it can be done by above method. I'm looking for extension that manages header links.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Manage category" add sub category say "offer of the day" under default category
and, change 'Is Active' and 'include in navigation menu' option to yes.

Save category.
clear the cache.
refresh the page to check the changes.

You just need to change the 'Is active' option no to disable the menu item "Offer of the day"